# Unawarded Badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Earlier today at one point A question I had posted an answer on had 23 votes with an accepted answer of 11 votes on the question, and supposedly met all of the requirements to receive the Populist badge. It remained like this for about six or so hours, after which the person who asked the question changed my answer to the accepted answer.

So what happened to my Populist badge? The accepted answer had more than 10 votes and my answer was double the score of the accepted answer. But I have no badge.

Answer (score 10):

Badges are awarded by scripts that run occasionally to check whether their conditions have been met. Either the script did not run in the time interval when the conditions were met and the eligibility was never noticed, or it did run in that interval, but the awarding of the badge itself is still “in the mail,” so to speak, and will be awarded later. No way to know for sure.

If it is still not awarded by tomorrow, likely the script never ran in the interval when the conditions were met.